# Ошибка в Visual Studio 19

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

[image: Картинка :)]

Проблема такова (если что, я совсем недавно в теме)
Смотрю значит урок по C# от Гоши и решил я значит создать свою функцию, а Vs выдает ошибку, хотя всё у него (в xamarin) работает нормально:

```
static int BBB (int a)
{
}
```

Ошибка  CS8652  Функция "статические локальные функции" сейчас находится на этапе предварительной версии и *является неподдерживаемой*. Для работы с предварительными версиями функций используйте версию языка "preview"

Что с этим делать?
(дать леща или сломать колени?)

Comment: попробуйте `использовать версию языка "preview"`

Comment: ....или объявить BBB вне Main

Answer (score 3):

Первая ошибка говорит о невозможности объявить статическую функцию в теле другой функции. (Вынеси её декларирование за пределы Main)

Вторая же - о том, что ты указал лишь сигнатуру функцию, а тело - нет.
(Добавь фигурные скобочки 'static void BBB() {}')

Умей читать ошибки, они довольно информативны:)

Comment: Спасибо большое. Я обычно всегда пытаюсь найти ответ в интернете, но тут моих недельных знаний не хватило, что бы понять в чем ошибка(хотя битый час я гуглил и т. д.). Поэтому я обратился сюда, хотя я изначально знал, что мой вопрос очень прост для многих